# Is it possible to use 2 MICs in Android device independently?

Tags: java, android, signal-processing, microphone, recording

I am working on a small audio processing project in Android using Java and Android Studio.

I happen to request the usage of the 2 microphones built in the device, the default one is always going the be used, but the second microphone I was wondering if it is possible to enable or disable it as needed. All the information I have found so far has been about starting the audioManager in different settings to use the 2 Microphones for noise cancellation and such but that does not provide independent control to each one.

Does anyone have any idea or has done something similar in the past?

Comment: Noise cancellation is usually done in hardware - therefore I would assume that actually you don't use one of the microphones, but the audio processing chip which uses both microphones and providing the "processed" audio stream. Knowing the chip and with root permissions you may be able to access the microphones in pass-through modes (if the chip supports it).